# How to animate a bar chart in chartist on creation

Tags: javascript, animation, charts, chartist.js

I'm using chartist.js to create and display a simple bar chart.
I can't wrap my head around the animate function and how to use it, i'm looking for a simple rising animation for the bars on the chart creation.
I found this [example](http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/easily-create-stunning-animated-charts-with-chart-js/chartjs-demo.html) from another question, and i'm looking to animate my bar chart the same as the bar chart in the example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching for some more examples in the official chartist.js and testing the chart draw event with the firefox debugger i reached the following solution:

```
chart.on('draw', function(data) {
    if(data.type == 'bar') {
        data.element.animate({
            y2: {
                dur: '0.2s',
                from: data.y1,
                to: data.y2
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, are your chartist charts redrawing on any event click or window resize?